# Enmap ensure not creating keys itself

Tags: javascript, object, bots, discord, discord.js

My code works fine if i create the database entry myself, however when I get someone else to try the entry isnt created (even though i used a .ensure to check)

Previously it created some entries automatically but im not sure what changed and then it stopped creating them, i've tried to change the code around but the only solution seems to be creating the entries manually.

The error usually occurs when calling the +elo command

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const Enmap = require("enmap");
client.elo = new Enmap({name: "elo"});
gameVar = 0;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)
    // List servers the bot is connected to
    console.log("Servers:")
    client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(" - " + guild.name)


    var generalChannel = client.channels.get("602976588543426596") // Replace with known channel ID
    generalChannel.send("--10 Man Bot--")
      generalChannel.send("To begin a game, type +join")
    generalChannel.send("")

    })
})

client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) { // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
        return
    }

    if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith("+")) {
        processCommand(receivedMessage)
    }
    if (receivedMessage.guild) {
      client.elo.ensure(`${receivedMessage.guild.id}-${receivedMessage.author.id}`, {
        user: receivedMessage.author.id,
        guild: receivedMessage.guild.id,
        elo: 0,
        console.log("entry created")
      });
    }
})

function processCommand(receivedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(1) // Remove the leading exclamation mark
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ") // Split the message up in to pieces for each space
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0] // The first word directly after the exclamation is the command
    let arguments = splitCommand.slice(1) // All other words are arguments/parameters/options for the command

    console.log("Command received: " + primaryCommand)

  if (primaryCommand == "elo") {
     const key = `${receivedMessage.guild.id}-${receivedMessage.author.id}`;
     return receivedMessage.channel.send(`ELO: ${client.elo.get(key, "elo")}`);
  }

bot_secret_token = 

client.login(bot_secret_token)
```

Here is the error message:

````
C:\Users\retski\node_modules\enmap\src\index.js:945
    if (!this.has(key)) throw new Err(`The key "${key}" does not exist in the enmap "${this.name}"`, 'EnmapPathError');
                        ^

EnmapPathError: The key "546829579290017793-269522297105285121" does not exist in the enmap "elo"
    at Map.[check] (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\enmap\src\index.js:945:31)
    at Map.get (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\enmap\src\index.js:227:19)
    at processCommand (C:\Users\retski\Desktop\10 man leffy\10man.js:69:60)
    at Client.client.on (C:\Users\retski\Desktop\10 man leffy\10man.js:29:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\retski\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `processCommand(receivedMessage)` before the `ensure`.

Try it like:

```
client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) { // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
        return;
    }

    if (receivedMessage.guild) {
        client.elo.ensure(`${receivedMessage.guild.id}-${receivedMessage.author.id}`, {
            user: receivedMessage.author.id,
            guild: receivedMessage.guild.id,
            elo: 0,
        });
        console.log('entry created');
    }

    if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith('+')) {
        processCommand(receivedMessage);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! I already did this and it fixed it, thankyou for your help though.